# External fingerprint scanner for non-rooted Android tablets

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, fingerprint, usb-otg, android-kernel

We want to develop an application where users will be using a handheld scanner for taking fingerprint of the customer via an android tablet. Now, I have a few questions:

1. I went through many discussions here as well as on other forums, but
   nobody really mentioned the status of the device, ie. Rooted or
   stock. Now does a non-rooted android tablet device support third
   party scanners?
2. I read somewhere that the device needs to have UVC
   kernel. Is this necessary? Or will any device with OTG support work?
3. Found a tablet from a french mobile security company, tablet named
   Tazpad. It provides an in-built biometric. Does anybody have any
   experience with it?
4. Is bluetooth scanner a possible option?

Please note that this will be for a banking organization and we cannot play with the kernel of the device. They are already opting to use Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1. But if this device does not support, then we can suggest any other tablet.

Thanks

Comment: galaxy tab s line has fingerprint scanner..refer http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/SM-T700NZWAXAR

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can these fingerprint scanner be used for custom apps? Like, they only seem to mention scanning feature only for unlocking. Can they be used for any other app?

Comment: Also, read somewhere that fingerprint scanner used for unlocking in Galaxy devices (including S5) are not completely reliable and are limited. This is for a banking application, so i guess going with a external scanner is one of the possible way.

Comment: yup it can be used in custom app ...refer-http://developer.samsung.com/develop#pass...generally any fingerprint is not reliable...you need to go with two factor authentication if you want to use fingerprint...however nowadays MS exchange also supports fingerprint authentication..earlier it used to be only pin and password

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to take the fingerprint image only? If yes, then Bluetooth Fingerprint scanner is a good option. You can use any Android Tablet or Smart Phone or iOS Device.